# Ultimate Thread Group parallel users as 0

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=UltimateThreadGroup) have a load graph with "expected parallel users count"

> trustworthy load preview graph

When Startup,Hold and Shutdown have 0 values the graph show 0 parallel users, although it seems that it should display the thread count, because the server is getting the users requests in same time, but graph display it as 0 users in parallel.

Is it not a valid concurrent users load? is it just a bug in display graph?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/7PCy5IU6U7M) is that it not a valid load

> Having zero startup+hold for time has no meaning for Ultimate Thread Group. The behavior in this case is unspecified and can be unexpected. Preview graph behavior is also unspecified, because it is impossible to display timeline of zero length.